# R - All or Partial String Matching?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of tweets for a sentiment analysis I am working on. I want to remove references to some proper names (for example, "Jeff Smith"). Is there a way to remove all or partial references to a name in the same command? Right now I am doing it the long way:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(text, c('(Jeff Smith) | (Jeff) | (Smith)' ))
```

But that obviously gets cumbersome as I add more names. Ideally there'd be some way to feed just "Jeff Smith" and then be able to match all or some of it. Does anybody have any ideas?

Some sample code if you would like to play with it:

```
tweets = data.frame(text = c('Smith said he’s not counting on Monday being a makeup day.', 
                   "Williams says that Steve Austin will miss the rest of the week",
                   "Weird times: Jeff Smith just got thrown out attempting to steal home",
                   "Rest day for Austin today",
                   "Jeff says he expects to bat leadoff", "Jeff", "No reference to either name"))
                   
name = c("Jeff Smith", "Steve Austin")
```

Comment: Try `'\\bJeff\\b.*\\bSmith'`

Comment: @akrun What command are you putting that into to find all strings with that pattern?

Comment: If you can provide a small reproducible example of text and expected output, it would be great to test

Comment: @akrun I added some to the original post

Comment: But, wouldn't this also matches something like `Jeff Austin`

Comment: @akrun It would, but let's just assume there are no "Jeff Austin's" in the tweets. I'm just trying to figure out a way to find all possible mentions of a proper name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226061/discussion-between-d-bryant-and-akrun).

Comment: I am in the chat

Comment: Based on the examples you showed, it is working.  If you can show an example that doesn't work, it would be easier to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, all of them should be TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
pat <-  str_c(gsub(" ", "\\b|\\b", str_c("\\b", name, "\\b"),
       fixed = TRUE), collapse="|")

tweets %>% 
      mutate(ind = str_detect(text, pat))
```

-output

```
#                                                               text   ind
#1           Smith said he’s not counting on Monday being a makeup day.  TRUE
#2       Williams says that Steve Austin will miss the rest of the week  TRUE
#3 Weird times: Jeff Smith just got thrown out attempting to steal home  TRUE
#4                                            Rest day for Austin today  TRUE
#5                                  Jeff says he expects to bat leadoff  TRUE
#6                                                                 Jeff  TRUE
#7                                          No reference to either name FALSE
```

Comment: This appears to be picking things up outside of the names in pat.

Comment: @D.Bryant can you try the new pattern

Comment: Yeah, still picking up outside patterns. Like for instance it's picking up tweets that are literally just hyperlinks.

Comment: @D.Bryant Can you update your example text as in the current example, all the rows have those values in the 'name'

Comment: @D.Bryant in the current example, I get all TRUE except the last element because all of the other have the word

Comment: @D.Bryant if you can tell me where it is getting wrong on the update output, it would be easier

Comment: Yeah I can see it's working on yours. I'm trying to reproduce on the actual dataset (which is 25k tweets or so). It returns the same number of results, even if I change the names in "name". I have no idea why it wouldn't work

Comment: @D.Bryant In the post, I used word boundary (`\\b`) to evaluate the word as a single unit

Comment: Does that mean your solution is more of an "and" solution than an "or"? Steffen's solution works for filtering the tweets down as intended, but it has a weird kink where it doesn't work if the tweet is a single word (it'll find "Jeff" in the middle of a sentence but it won't return a tweet that just says "Jeff").

Comment: @D.Bryant it is more of a `"or"` solution

Comment: @D.Bryant It seems to work for the 6th element with only "Jeff"

Comment: I figured out why. First, you had your str_detect in a mutate, whereas I was trying to use it to filter. Once I changed that step, it worked. As for it not working on individual words, I then realized my workflow was changing splitting tweets into words and using "to_lower". Your command was case sensitive, but all of my words were already lowercase. Changed the names to lowers and it works. So your solution is a winner! Thank you so much for all of your help today! Gold star for you!

Answer (score 1):

Not a beauty, but it works.

```
#example data
namelist <- c('Jeff Smith', 'Kevin Arnold')

namelist_spreaded <- strsplit(namelist, split = ' ')

f <- function(x) {
  paste0('(',
         paste(x, collapse = ' '),
         ') | (',
         paste(x, collapse = ') | ('),
         ')')
}
lapply(namelist_spreaded, f)
```